# Adding FOREIGN KEY Constraint in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

How can i add FOREIGN KEY constraint in the referrer_id(same as profile id) column? Since the column name contains parentheses it is throwing error

```
ALTER table Referrals ADD Constraint fk_referrer_ID 
       FOREIGN KEY(referrer_id(same as profile id)) REFERENCES Profiles(profile_id)
```

ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'referrer_id(same as profile id)'.

Comment: `referrer_id(same as profile id)` is this your column name ? or just `referrer_id`

Answer (score 2):

Use below query, column name delimited by brackets ([ ]):

```
ALTER table Referrals ADD Constraint fk_referrer_ID FOREIGN KEY([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) REFERENCES Profiles(profile_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `referrer_id` is your column name

```
ALTER table Referrals ADD Constraint fk_referrer_ID 
        FOREIGN KEY(referrer_id) REFERENCES Profiles(profile_id)
```

You don't to specify that it is *same as profile id* in foreign key, `REFERENCES Profiles(profile_id)` conveys that message to compiler.

or if you really have a ugly column name(`referrer_id(same as profile id)`) then you need to use square brackets to escape the special characters present in your column name

```
ALTER table Referrals ADD Constraint fk_referrer_ID 
         FOREIGN KEY([referrer_id(same as profile id)]) REFERENCES Profiles(profile_id)
```